# Compare SQL Query outcome to a fixed integer

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently working on a school project, it's a website which has to save and take back information to and from a database. But I'm having an issue with comparing the retrieving with a solid number.

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['totaal'])) {
  $gebruikersnaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['gebruikersnaam']);
  $punten = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['punten']);

    $query = "SELECT points FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $minimal = 15;
    if ($results < $minimal) {
      header('location: no.php');
    }
    else if ($results > $minimal){
        header('location: yes.php');
        }
    }
    ?>
```

So it has to decide if this number is higher or lower then 15, but it always take me to `no.php` even though in my database it says the integer is higher.

Comment: Are you sure `$results` is a number, and not a string?

Comment: what do you get from `var_dump($results);`?

Comment: I get array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "38" ["points"]=> string(2) "38" }  It sais its a string so maybe thats the problem, do you know how I should fix this? In my database it's an Int(11).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after `$results = mysqli_query ($db, $query)`:

```
$points = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
```

And change your `if ($results < $minimal)` with `if ($points['points'] < $minimal)`

Comment: I did this, and it fixed a few issues, but I'm still having trouble converting the points to an integer. I use this: $results = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
 $points= (int)$results;
  var_dump($points); But the output is int(1), even though it should be 38 in this case.